# Using non memory optimised tables in Natively Compiled Stored Procedure without custom table types

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, oltp

I am trying to rewrite a stored procedure to Natively compiled stored procedure. The procedure refers to 20 tables, these tables are normal tables (non memory optimised) and I am using 5 views related to it. Is it possible to create a Natively Compiled stored procedure without converting any of these objects to Memory optimised tables?

Comment: I think the answer is no, they must operate on memory-optimized tables, but the docs don't explicitly say they must be, just imply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively compiled procedures cannot access non-in-memory tables.

See Aaron's answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180172/use-natively-compiled-stored-procedures-in-disk-based-tables.